# The previous text (has not | does not | not) written correctly

Tags: verbs, negation

I have a simple sentence, but I have some confusion on it.

**What is the correct choice and why ?**

> The previous text (**has not** | **does not** | **not** | **something else**) written correctly.

I choose *"has not"* and I don't know if my choice is correct or not.

P.S. Do not be surprised if you see that sentence is very easy, I'm still beginner.

Comment: "is not written" or "was not written"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have left out a word, none of the answers are correct.

The only ways the sentence can be correctly completed are as follows:

- The previous text **has not been** written correctly.
- The previous text **is not** written correctly.